# Which is the best way to obtain data similar to Google Knowldge Graph

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition

I need data which is similar to GKG primarily for Named Entity Recognition. Basically I want to use the context(extra information) behind an entity for entity recognition. What is the suggested way of using the data?

I found out that DBPedia provides what is needed but I felt the data is incomplete. For some entities like "Larry_Page", in instance_types dump of 3.8 version, the content seems to be

```
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Person> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Larry_Page> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> .
```

So, for "Larry_Page" the information restricts until "Person" type. 
   Is there any way I can get complete hierarchy of entities with their types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Freebase? In Freebase they have a /common/topic/notable_for Computer Scientist for Larry Page. The problem with these databases is that you have to do a lot of engineering (magic) to pick the right predicates. And you always have some noise.

P.S. Sorry for posting a response, I don't have enough reputation to add comments :)